# Do we have a policy on video questions?

Tags: discussion

In this question [Bike won't shift into 2 largest rear cogs (lowest gears)](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32693/bike-not-changing-last-2-gears-correctly), the main content is the video.

Do we want our questions to be like this?

**Pro**

- Gen X,Y,Z like video as a medium.

**Con**

- The body of the question is hidden from our current search techniques.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

While we don't have a specific policy regarding link/video only questions, we *do* have [one regarding answers](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

> **Provide context for links**
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context
>   around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is
>   and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an
>   important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes
>   permanently offline.

I think the logic behind this policy applies to questions equally well.

It's certainly feasible that this user could take down the video or delete their YouTube account. YouTube could change their link structure, or (admittedly highly unlikely) YouTube could fold entirely.

Whatever the case, we want the question to provide value to future users. That being the case, I believe that *any* link or video should provide textual context, whether it's in a question or an answer.

Comment: I think the same basic policy should apply to the questions, like you said.. As much as possible of the details of the question should be in the text. Images (using the stack exchange hosting) won't go away, but text helps the question be found. Videos on youtube could go away, and also don't help the question be found.

Comment: Also, in this particular case, I think some images would have been sufficient to show everything better than the videos did. Videos are most useful for showing something in motion.

Comment: A transcript from the video might be an "easy win" for providing the "textual content" you mentioned. And I learned today that youtube can provide a transcript automatically: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/34934/70298

Answer (score 3):

I think we have a few video questions in the past.

My view is that a video question should have a summary of the video as well as the video. The video doesn't hurt, but most of us (esp. if we SE on phones) will find it more convenient to read the text.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed-the question should be capable of standing alone should the video disappear from the internet.  I guess the same goes for any other embedded media that isn't hosted by stackexchange.  Imgur photos could vanish too.

That said if a picture's worth a thousand words, and since video is 25 pictures/second, that works out at 25,000 words/second effective.

Should stackexchange look to providing hosting for relevant video and pictures?